# Continuous characteristic function(s) on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces

I have been working on the following example for sometime now and wanted to ensure my reasoning is correct. This example is from a chapter in my textbook on *The Continuity of Maps between Metric spaces*.

> Is there a continuous characteristic function, $X_{A}$, on $\mathbb{R}$? Also, if $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ show that $X_A$ is continuous at each point of the interior of $A^{o}$ (the interior or $A$).

Note that the characteristic function $X_A$ I am referring to (usually denoted with *chi*, but MathJax doesn't take subscripts to this greek letter well) between two metric spaces $(M,d_{1})$ and $(N,d_{2})$ is defined on a subset $A \subset M$ such that  $X_{A}(x) := 1$ if $x \in A$ and $X_{A}(x) := 0$ if $x \notin A$.

---

$\bullet$ For: Is there a continuous characteristic function, $X_{A}$, on $\mathbb{R}$?

Yes, take $\mathbb{R}$ as a subset of itself. So $X_{\mathbb{R}}(x) = 1$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$. Therefore, the preimage, $X_{\mathbb{R}}^{-1}(\{1\}) = \mathbb{R}$ is closed and since the preimage of a closed set is closed, $X_{\mathbb{R}}$ is continuous. As well, if we take $\emptyset \subset \mathbb{R}$: $X_{\emptyset}(x) = 0$. So $X_{\emptyset}^{-1}(\{0\}) = \emptyset$ is closed. By similar reasoning, the preimage of a closed set is closed so we can conclude $X_{\emptyset}$ is continuous.

$\bullet$ For: Also, if $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ show that $X_A$ is continuous at each point of the interior of $A^{o}$ (the interior or $A$).

We know that $A^{o} \subset A$, so let $x \in A^{o}$. So we know $X_A(\{x\}) =\{1\}$ since $x$ is also in $A$. Therefore, $X_A^{-1}(\{1\}) = \{x\}$ where $x$ is any element in $A$, and since $A^{o} \subset A$, it can be any element in the interior. So since the preimage of a closed set is closed, $X_A$ is continuos at each point of the interior of $A$, and also continuous on all of $A$.

I feel like this reasoning is correct, but I have my doubts. Also, are there any other points of continuity such as in $A^c$? Any criticism is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true that $\chi_A^{-1}\big(\{1\}\big)=\{x\}$ for $x\in\operatorname{int}A$: $\chi_A^{-1}\big(\{1\}\big)=\{x\}$ iff $A=\{x\}$, in which case $x\notin\operatorname{int}A$. Remember, by definition $$\chi_A^{-1}\big(\{1\}\big)=\{y\in\Bbb R:\chi_A(y)=1\}=A\,.$$

To show that $\chi_A$ is continuous at $x$, let $\epsilon>0$. Since $x\in\operatorname{int}A$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $(x-\delta,x+\delta)\subseteq A$. Thus, if $|y-x|<\delta$, then $\chi_A(y)=1$, so $|\chi_A(y)-\chi_A(x)|=0<\epsilon$, and $\chi_A$ is therefore continuous at $x$.

Comment: Thank you, Brian. That makes a lot more sense. Is my reasoning for a $X_A$ being a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ incorrect as well?

Comment: @TaylorRendon: You’re welcome. You mean the argument that $\chi_{\Bbb R}$ and $\chi_\varnothing$ are continuous? That argument is fine. (And those are the only two sets $A\subseteq\Bbb R)$ for which $\chi_A$ is continuous.)

Comment: Wonderful. One last little detail I've been thinking of: since we know now that $X_A$ is continuous at each point of the interior of $A$, are there any other points of continuity such as in the exterior of the set $A$?

Comment: @TaylorRendon: Yes, by essentially the same argument: the exterior of $A$ is the interior of $\Bbb R\setminus A$. Or you can note that $\chi_{\Bbb R\setminus A}=1-\chi_A$, so the two characteristic functions are continuous at the same points.

Comment: Gotcha! One last question if I may: shouldn't our notation be $X_{A^{o}}$ since we are considering the continuity at each point in the interior of $A$, or does it not matter since $A^{o}$ is a subset of $A$?

Comment: @TaylorRendon: No, because we’re talking about where the function $\chi_A$ is continuous, and $\chi_A$ is by definition the function that is $1$ on $A$ and $0$ off $A$. Take $A=[0,1]$, for instance; the interior of $A$ is $(0,1)$, and $\chi_{[0,1]}\ne\chi_{(0,1)}$, because $[0,1]\ne(0,1)$. Those two function happen to be continuous at the same points, but they disagree at the other two points and are therefore different functions.